# What is the differents between Organic Group and Group module at Drupal?

Tags: php, drupal-7, drupal-8, drupal-modules, organic-groups

I have checked both Group and OG modules. Both grouped content , audience. But group module structure different.

I have a feature in drupal 7 , developed totally based on Organic Group module. When I am going to migrate it , I found there is no stable version of OG module available in Drupal 8. So I am facing problems.

Can I use Drupal 8 Group module to implement this feature which is based on OG module in Drupal 7. If I can implement this feature using Group module in Drupal 8, then how can  I migrate all data ? Because both structure totally different.

Anyone can help me to find out this issue?

Answer (score 0):

Organic Groups is in development for D8 and isn't stable. Group looks stable in D8. The functionality looks similar enough to where you could migrate the data between Drupal versions. However, to preserve the data you'd have to do quite a bit of development with the "migrate" module in D8 which usually comes with some contrib modules as well along with a custom migration:

1. Setup the Group module in D8 with the similar groups config as D7
   Organic Groups
2. Setup the migrate module in D8 and point it to D7:
   https://www.drupal.org/docs/drupal-apis/migrate-api/migrate-api-overview
3. Create a custom migration to migrate D7 Organic Groups data to D8
   Groups

Depending on how much data you have, I might recommend manually recreating it rather than migrating it. But if its 1000s of records, some level of custom PHP and SQL queries will be involved.